# How to enable a non default OpenSSL Cipher Suite

Tags: openssl

I have an install of OpenSSL 1.1.1f as per Ubuntu 20.04 and
I specifically want the TLS v1.2 suite `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8` (`ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM8`) enabled.

[image: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8 is available]

How do I configured OpenSSL to allow the use of that cipher suite for other apps that use the OpenSSL install for TLS?

Details about my use case:
I have a .NET(6) app, and [.NET uses the present OpenSSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/cryptography/5.0/default-cipher-suites-for-tls-on-linux) 1.1.1 or greater install as the [underlying TLS provider on Linux](https://omairmajid.com/posts/2021-08-25-using-.net-in-centos-stream-9/). So afaik when that app uses OpenSSL, OpenSSL needs to be configured to allow for the CCM cipher suites.(it will use the `openssl.cnf` as per `openssl version -d`)

I see in the config section of the OpenSSL manual that the module I am interested configuring is `ssl_conf`, and so I created the following cnf:

```
openssl_conf = default_conf

[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
CipherString = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM8
```

but this doesn't allow the app to use TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8. When my TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8 exclusive client tries to connect it gets a handshake 40 failure, as the app internally throws an `'Interop.OpenSsl.SslException' in System.Net.Security.dll`

However, I confirmed this config file works because if I use the following cnf with instead TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 as the sole filter in the cipher string, then the app can exclusively use TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 and it works as expected (a ...GCM_SHA256 exclusive client can connect):

```
...
[system_default_sect]
CipherString = ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

How do I enable TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8?

And I am not sure how to confirm the enabling of CCM... I am expecting that when I run `openssl ciphers -v` (with no cipher string filter) that I will see CCM8 listed, just as TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 is listed.

I read the Configuration section of this cook book: https://www.feistyduck.com/library/openssl-cookbook/online/openssl-command-line/configuration.html, but I think I need some experienced advice to explain why I cant just use CCM8.

Comment: What do you mean 'at the OS level'? The OS does not use OpenSSL; programs like apache(httpd) nginx php python curl wget and many more do. Some programs allow you to configure their cipherlist in a program-specific way; many (always or sometimes) use OpenSSL's default cipherlist for SSL/TLS, whose pre-compiled value excludes CCM, but (since 1.1.0) can be changed by an OpenSSL config file which defaults to /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf but can be overridden by env var OPENSSL_CONF; see man 5 config (openssl-config in some other systems).

Comment: I will check out `openssl-config` and that is great if I don't have to recompile, and can just "activate" CCM via the configs. And yes I meant for other apps to use, such as those you listed. Updated question.

Comment: I found the Micro Focus guide to OpenSsl very useful for getting a higher overview of OpenSSL configuration https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/visual-cobol/VC40/CSWin/HROSSROPEN02.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "enable" a non default cipher suite for use with a .NET app one must configure OpenSSL. Many framework apps such as .NET apps use OpenSSL under the hood, one can create an OpenSSL config, and then set the environment variable `OPENSSL_CONF` to the full path to the config file.
Most apps that use OpenSSL will use the `OPENSSL_CONF` environment variable to get the config file that should be used when using OpenSSL. OpenSSL will use a default `openssl.cnf` that doesn't enable all cipher suites to ensure apps don't use less secure cipher suites.

In the case of enabling an app to use `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8` one could create the following config file:

```
# myCustomOpenSSL.cnf
openssl_conf = default_conf

[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

#CipherString is a colon separated list of terms that filter what TLS v1.2 suites OpenSSL will allow use of. 
[system_default_sect]
CipherString = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM8
```

and then set `OPENSSL_CONF` to `/example/path/myCustomOpenSSL.cnf` before starting the application from the same shell instance (so the `OPENSSL_CONF`is correct), or if you are developing the application you can set `OPENSSL_CONF` in your applications code.

...

My issue was that I had failed to provide the app with a ECDSA Cert. In order to use `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8` the app *must* have an ECDSA certificate - that is it is signed with a ECDSA key. I was working in Visual Studio and running my app via WSL. Visual Studio installs default development certificates in `/etc/ssl/certs`. These default dev certs are RSA based, so while the app didn't complain about not having a certificate, it had an incompatible certificate hence the `'Interop.OpenSsl.SslException' in System.Net.Security.dll` exception.

So I configured the app to use ECDSA based certificate over the default development RSA based certificate and voila!

So the cnf file I created was working to "enable" `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8`.

Note: Using an OpenSSL cnf for cipher suite selection is not required with .NET as [you can create a CipherSuitePolicy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/cryptography/5.0/default-cipher-suites-for-tls-on-linux#recommended-action) to define your apps cipher suites within the code.